# Seeing warning messages after upgrading mariadb-java-client jar

Tags: java, logging, mariadb, slf4j, mariadb-connector-j

Within my codebase, I've upgraded `mariadb-java-client` jar from `2.5.2` to `3.2.0` within my pom.xml file (using Maven to build here). Without any additional changes, my application and tests works fine. But I've noticed warning within my logs.

```
12-14 22:20:43.429|main|Slf4JLogger.warn|WARN|Error: 1049-42000: Unknown database 'jason_test_db'
12-14 22:20:43.640|main|Slf4JLogger.warn|WARN|Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'jason_test_db.TEST_SUB_TYPE' doesn't exist
12-14 22:20:43.642|main|Slf4JLogger.warn|WARN|Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'jason_test_db.TEST_TYPE' doesn't exist
12-14 22:20:43.642|main|Slf4JLogger.warn|WARN|Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'jason_test_db.TEST_TYPE' doesn't exist
12-14 22:20:43.643|main|Slf4JLogger.warn|WARN|Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'jason_test_db.TEST_TYPE_NAMES_' doesn't exist
```

I'm unsure about the warning messages and can't understand why do they show up in the first place. Any idea was to what was changed within the `mariadb-java-client` jar for such warnings to show up? Can these warnings be suppressed?

Comment: I guess suppressing might involve creating the database/tables.  Are these FK constraints that weren't previously tested in previous `mariadb-java-client` versions. There aren't any TYPE/SUB_TYPE references that exist in the [mariadb-connector j source code](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j) so I assume they are part of your application.

Comment: TYPE/SUB_TYPE is within my application.

Comment: I've also noticed in the newer version that `connection.getMetaData().getTables(null, null "%", null)` returns tables from all other databases as well. Even though the connectionUrl contains the database name.